# Detect delete key using UIKeyCommand

Tags: ios, cocoa, uikeycommand

Anyone know how to detect the "delete" key using `UIKeyCommand` on iOS 7?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Simple really - need to look for the backspace character "\b"

Comment: This didn't work for me. It states "invalid escape sequence". So I changed it to `"\\b"` but this results in the method not getting called upon hitting "delete" on the Mac keyboard. `UIKeyCommand(input: "\\b", modifierFlags: nil, action: "methodToCall:")`

Comment: I found it. Use "\\" in Swift.

Comment: @Joey try `\u{08}` instead of `\\b`

Answer (score 33):

As people were having problems with Swift, I figured a small, complete example in both Objective C and Swift might be a good answer.

Note that Swift doesn't have a `\b` escape character for backspace, so you need to use a simple Unicode scalar value escape sequence of `\u{8}`. This maps to the same old-school [ASCII control character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_code_chart) number 8 ("control-H", or ^H in [caret notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation)) for backspace as `\b` does in Objective C.

Here's an Objective C view controller implementation that catches backspaces:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

// The View Controller must be able to become a first responder to register
// key presses.
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}

- (NSArray *)keyCommands {
    return @[
        [UIKeyCommand keyCommandWithInput:@"\b" modifierFlags:0 action:@selector(backspacePressed)]
    ];
}

- (void)backspacePressed {
    NSLog(@"Backspace key was pressed");
}

@end
```

And here's the equivalent view controller in Swift:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
        return true;
    }

    override var keyCommands: [UIKeyCommand]? {
        return [
            UIKeyCommand(input: "\u{8}", modifierFlags: [], action: #selector(backspacePressed))
        ]
    }

    @objc func backspacePressed() {
        NSLog("Backspace key was pressed")
    }

}
```

Comment: Type 'UIKeyModifierFlags' has no member 'allZeros'

Comment: @purefusion I have now updated the code to work with the very latest version of Swift. Key differences: `canBecomeFirstResponder` and `keyCommands` are now overridden properties, not methods, `modifierFlags` is now an `OptionSet` so you can pass an empty set if there are no modifiers rather than use the `allZeros` kludge, and I'm using the new `#selector` syntax. Tested and working fine with an external keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS 15 there is a [`UIKeyCommand.inputDelete` constant](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uikeycommand/3783578-inputdelete) that works:

```
UIKeyCommand(title: "Delete Widget",
             action: #selector(WidgetViewController.deleteWidget(_:)),
             input: UIKeyCommand.inputDelete)
```

Answer (score -2):

You can always try UIKeyInput. *https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKeyInput_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIKeyInput/deleteBackward*

The function should be

- (void)deleteBackward

Comment: Implementing `UIKeyInput` presents a keyboard though when becoming first responder.