# Invalid escape sequence in literal: "\b"

Tags: ios, string, swift, escaping

I need to be able to create a String that is `"\b"`. But when I try to, Xcode throws a compile-time error: Invalid escape sequence in literal. I don't understand why though, `"\r"` works just fine. If I put `"\\b"` then that's what is actually stored in the String, which is not what I need - I only need one backslash. To me, this seems to be a Swift oddity because it works just fine in Objective-C.

```
let str = "\b" //Invalid escape sequence in literal
NSString *str = @"\b"; //works great
```

I need to generate this string because `"\b"` is the only way to detect when the user pressed 'delete' when using `UIKeyCommand`:

```
let command = UIKeyCommand(input: "\b", modifierFlags: nil, action: "didHitDelete:")
```

How can I work around this issue?

EDIT: It **really** doesn't want to generate a String that is only `"\b"`, this does not work - it stays the original value:

```
var delKey = "\rb"
delKey = delKey.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("r", withString: "", options: .LiteralSearch, range: nil)
```

Comment: Incidentally, your string replacement doesn't work because in Swift, "\rb" is a carriage return character followed by the letter "b" (literally the bytes 0D 98). That string doesn't have an "r" in it to replace...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Swift equivalent of `\b` is `\u{8}`. It maps to ASCII control code 8, just like `\b` in Objective C. I've tested this and found it to work fine with `UIKeyCommand`, in [this earlier answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22068308/detect-delete-key-using-uikeycommand/27608606#27608606).

Example snippet:

```
func keyCommands() -> NSArray {
    return [
        UIKeyCommand(input: "\u{8}", modifierFlags: .allZeros, action: "backspacePressed")
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't believe it is supported.

Based on the Swift documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html:

> String literals can include the following special Unicode characters:
>
> The escaped special characters \0 (null character), \ (backslash), \t
>   (horizontal tab), \n (line feed), \r (carriage return), \" (double
>   quote) and \' (single quote)
>
> An arbitrary Unicode scalar, written as
>   \u{n}, where n is between one and eight hexadecimal digits

The ASCII for the \b is 8. If you do the following, you'll see these results

```
let bs = "\u{8}"
var str = "Simple\u{8}string"

println(bs) // Prints ""
println("bs length is \(bs.lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding))") // Prints 1
println(str) // Prints Simplestring

let space = "\u{20}"

println(space) // Prints " "
println("space length is \(space.lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding))") // Prints 1

str = "Simple\u{20}string"
println(str) // Prints Simple string
```

It looks like while ASCII 8 "exists", it is "ignored".

Comment: So this is simply impossible at this point in time, there's no way to workaround it?

Comment: Sorry dude it is sort of looking like that. What are you trying to do with the backspace? Perhaps there is another way of faking it by using a hidden UITextFields and something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977934/detect-backspace-in-uitextfield/6637821#6637821. Or you could always try and figure out what the value is by trying something like this: https://gist.github.com/steventroughtonsmith/7515380. You can see the what is returned on pressing backspace.